# Very slow instantiation of json objects from rails postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, nosql

I have a RoR service that stores large json objects in a few postgres json fields. The model has and 3 json fields each that hold blobs of json up to 100,000 characters in length. Looks like:

```
  name: "Name",
  description: "A thing",
  things: { [...], [...], [...], ... },
  more_things: { [...], [...], [...], ... }
  even_more: { ... }
```

Now I know this isn't ideal, but when querying for these the ActiveRecord load takes minuscule time (~2ms) but then hangs as (I assume) the json fields are initialized into objects.

I realize I may be going about this in the wrong way, these are essentially static json blobs that are frequently referenced but essentially never changed. I'm looking for optimization/caching suggestions to make this not be unbearably slow. Would a noSQL option be better?

Thanks

Comment: How long is it "hanging" when decoding these JSON docs? Can you do some echos before and after (preferably with timestamps) to make sure that's actually the hangup?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? When I run a benchmark on getting 10 of these, the db load takes 18ms but then it hangs for 16 seconds

Comment: What are the use cases you have with those records? E.g. when you only need `:name` and `:description` most of the times, you could alter the database scheme to move the other columns into a separate table thus avoiding having to instantiate the fields all the time.

Comment: On that same note, you could just query the properties you need using jsonb and not alter the schema.

Comment: well poo that's PHP, not rails.. I don't use rails so I'm unsure of the equivalent

Comment: I think you are right that Active Record has a lot of overhead when building these objects with large json fields.  Instead of using AR you could query the database directly using raw sql.